# MySQLi SELECT statement requires LIMIT

Tags: php, select, mysqli, limit

I'm trying to display a listing of 6 columns from a database table. This table happens to have a bit over 30,000 records. What I've used in the past worked but this time the list ends at 10,939 records and won't display at all unless I add the LIMIT clause to the line.

The table name is phpbb_users and the column I'm sorting on is username. The goal is to display a listing of everyone, displaying about 8 other data fields.
If I use this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY username";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

and then follow with the usual while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) stuff that displays every line the query fails and no listing appears.

If I change the code to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY username LIMIT 10000";
```

the listing appears, but it only displays the first 10,000 records.

Is there some kind of limit to how many records can be read in a MySQLi SELECT query? I didn't have this problem when I was running PHP 5.6 and MySQL but I just upgraded to PHP 7.2 and MySQLi and the new code isn't working the same way.

Comment: Use pagination.

Comment: Use pagination, who is realistically going to look at 10,000+ lines on a web page

Comment: I doubt it fails completely silent. So instead of asking “is there some something, that …”, go figure out what the actual error was.

Comment: Would be nice to know the error message, did you check the error logs for error messages yet

Comment: Does it fail silently, or does it time out?

Comment: It would then be useful to see the code around where the actuall error occurs. My initial bet is blown memory limit

Comment: First of all, it is never smart to load more than 30.000 records at once. This causes to many traffic. Imagine would you as a human being go through a list of 30k entries? NO.

And imagine how many users do use this search feature of your application? Let us say 10 at the same time. Then every time when a user load the search page your database has to deliver more than 300k entries. That would bring down your application.

Comment: I understand all that but it's an older program that one person uses to find a member by using CTRL-F to retrieve email address, phone, etc. I plan on replacing it with a new page that allows entry of the parameter and displaying the one or few results that match. But I did want to get this working because it used to prior to the PHP upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I did check the error_log in FileZilla. It appears to be a memory limit.

[12-Jan-2021 13:14:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39828320 bytes) in /home/tiffinrv/public_html/staff/member_search.php on line 202

In the past an admin would display the list and use CTRL-F to find the record they wanted. I plan on writing some code to make that easier to do by using a SELECT and INNER JOIN to access that info from two tables but first needed to see why this no longer worked. But next I'm going to have to figure out what to do about the memory limit. It worked fine before upgrading but it appears that the newer version has more overhead and leaves less memory available for this. Hopefully have enough RAM on the server and just can get it configured/allocated better.

I noticed another set of errors in the log.

[12-Jan-2021 13:14:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/tiffinrv/public_html/staff/member_search.php on line 54

I have assigned values to variables used in my database connection. It works just fine as I have in the past but this error warns of future issues. From what I gather I may need to define them, such as define('USERNAME','myname;'); rather than just establish values, such as $username = 'myname'; to prevent issues with future upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to raise the memory limit in WHM and now my memory error messages are gone. But the list displays 10,000 records if I use the LIMIT 10000 in my query. But if I raise the limit to 20000, or remove the LIMIT entirely, the listing stops at around 5,000 records but the actual count varies each time I run it.

Comment: You should DEFINITELY AVOID LOADING all of the users records,that you have in your database. Instead load only a subset of your records an show them to the user. For example 100 records? And then load other records by pagination.

For the search you can use an input field. The user inputs the text to be searched in your users table. You can send this search text via AJAX request to your back end. And the search takes place in your database not in the front end. That is much more efficient.